# partial response to web service query

Tags: java, web-services, url

I have this little bit of code in a Java program :

`URL combination = new URL (MainApp.getDatabaseURL().concat("combinations/?display=[unite]&filter[ean13]=["+ean13List+"]"));`

Then I use a bufferedreader to read lines. It is supposed to get between ten and fifty specific line from a database through a web service, the response is an xml file. My problem here is that my program doesn't wait long enough (or something like that) for the response to be complete. I don't get all the lines that I should get, and that I know for I have accessed the web service through chrome with the very same URL and got all the lines I wanted.
What can I do to fix this ?